# Problem printing Booklet in Indesign to a PDF using postscript

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat

I have this message in Acrobat Distiller when trying to PDF a booklet from Indesign CS5: Acrobat Distiller 9.5.1 Started: Wednesday, 1 August 2012 at 10:22 AM Adobe PostScript software version: 3018.101 CID support library initialization completed.

Error in /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PDF/Settings/PDFX4 2008.joboptions: /CheckCompliance out of range

I proceeded exactly as suggested in previous posts in this forum using Print booklet> postscript> saving the .ps file and importing it to Acrobat. When choosing the Postscript, all the print settings are greyed out. The booklet only partially converts to PDF (half of the pages and not the spreads). Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong and how I can remedy that problem? Thanks. Isabelle

Am on a Mac Snow Leopard/ Adobe Acrobat 9 pro /Indesign CS5

Comment: Did you preflight the Indesign document? Sounds like you may have an image or object on a page that is causing an issue. Check the Indesign page AFTER the laste page which gets converted to PDF.

Comment: Hi Scott, there is nothing wrong with my Indesign document. If I export it to Acrobat, the PDF is fine. The problem is trying to print PDF with the Print booklet feature using postscript, the only way apparently to do it. It looks like I need to adjust the print settings to landscape maybe but as I said before, when choosing to print to Postscript, the print settings are not available (greyed out). I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Well the error you posted basically states "There's something in this postscript file which is not compliant with PDFX4 options" This leads me to believe that while exporting a PDF from Indesign may work with other job options, you've got an object which is not standard on one of the pages.

Comment: In addition to choosing postscript, have you checked the printer setup and also chosen the correct PPD?

Answer (score 3):

There was a change to the way OS X handles PDF, introduced in Snow Leopard, that changed (well, trashed) the standard Adobe Print to PDF workflow. You can find detailed information and the workaround on the InDesign Secrets blog [here](http://indesignsecrets.com/acrobats-adobe-pdf-printer-replaced-in-snow-leopard.php).

There is also an [Adobe Tech Note](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-print-pdfs-mac-os.html) on the subject.

In essence, the steps are:

- Remove the Adobe PDF Printer in OS X System Preferences (happens automatically on update/upgrade of Acrobat from 9.0).
- Use the "Save As Adobe PDF" option under "PDF" in the OS X print dialog.

To quote Adobe PDF expert Leonard Rosenthol (as quoted in Steve Werner's InDesign Secrets post, referenced above):

> In a nutshell, Snow Leopard no longer supports the necessary OS features we need to install a Distiller-based printer.  It’s just as well, as that print path (of PDF->PS->PDF) is REALLY SLOW and full of a HUGE number of bugs for many years now that we couldn’t fix due to how the Apple printing system works ?. With Snow Leopard, you now have a new PDF Workflow entry (the things in the “PDF” menu in the print dialog) called “Adobe PDF” which will convert the Apple-based PDF into an Adobe-based PDF using your supplied/chosen Job Options.  It does so via native PDF transcoding – no Postscript here!! So we still provide a method for creation of Adobe-quality PDFs – but it’s FASTER and MORE reliable!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out one of the InDesign plug-ins for doing booklets. They work by creating a new InDesign file, rather than using making booklets a print-time feature.  You can then use InDesign's PDF Export feature to create a PDF file if you need one.